# Using a stream of IPs to send http post requests to them

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, httprequest, java.util.concurrent

I'm working on a Java project which has one instance of a consumer list (every consumer has IP(String) and Preferences(Custome Object) ).
I'm listening to events from tweeter and every time I get an update from tweeter I want to send it to the consumers with the suitable preference by HTTP post request.

I thought about doing it with a parallelStream

```
personList.parallelStream()
.filter(...)
.map(person -> sendHTTP(person.getIp()))
```

Can converting the list instance to a CopyOnWriteArrayList be helpful?

```
personConcurrent.parallelStream()
.filter(...)
.map(person -> sendHTTP(person.getIp()))
```

What is the best way of doing this to get the best preformance regarding many HTTP post requests?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not doing the request in the stream itself is the right way. Not using the stream at all is probably even better in that case. Just write a normal loop and submit N tasks on an `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolExecutor` or ... that takes care of scheduling the requests.

Comment: As luk2302 said it's not good practice, ```parallelStream()``` uses internally ForAndJoin Pool mechanism. There are better than that, for Instance ```newFixedThreadPool``` gives better performance for IO operations.  In your case, collect the IPs and create ExecutorService then execute it in parallel.